# Not able to access session attributes in freemarker templates

Tags: java, email, struts2, freemarker

I have an action class which sets the session attributes `A` and `B`. I know values exists and they are not `null`.

In Freemarker template I am trying to get those values by using below expression

```
<#if session.A?exists>
  ${session.A}
</#if>
```

or

```
<@s.property value="%{#session.A}" />
```

In get below error,

```
<#if session.A?exists> Expression session is undefined on line 39
```

As far as I know with Freemarker Struts2 , we don't need to do any extra setup since Freemarker's jars are bundled with Struts2, I was thinking Freemarker will have access to value stack, but it seems I am getting something wrong here. Can someone take a look and see what's that I am missing ? I am on S2 2.15.3

Below is additional code, In action class, I add values to session object,

```
sessionMap.put("A", A);
        sessionMap.put("B", B);
        System.out.println("Inside loop test 2!");           
        String[] args = null;
        SendEmail.main(args);           
        return "success";
```

Now sendEmail class contains freemarker configuration,

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(SendEmail.class, "");
            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("SendEmail.ftl");              
            Map<String,String> rootMap = new HashMap<>();
            Writer out = new StringWriter();
            try {
                template.process(rootMap, out);
            } catch (TemplateException | IOException templateException) {
                logger.error("Freemarker Template processing exception", templateException);
            }
            body.setContent(out.toString(), "text/html");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(body);
            message.setContent(multipart, "text/html");
            Transport.send(message);
```

Session map is declared as

```
 private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
```

Answer (score 4):

Variable names are case sensitive in Freemarker, and session is stored under `Session` (capitalized).
So, your code should be:

```
<#if Session.A?exists>
    ${Session.A}
</#if>
```

Or (as `exists` built-in is deprecated)

```
<#if Session.A??>
    ${Session.A}
</#if>
```

Comment: -- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression Session is undefined on line 39

Answer (score 1):

Since `HttpSession` doesn't have a `get` method you need to use one of the methods provided in there to operate with the session. Use `getAttribute` method to get session value.

```
${session.getAttribute('A')}
```

Above will work if you use FreeMarker template inside Struts2.

In your case you are not setting session map to the model. Change your `rootMap` declaration to `Map<String, Object>` and put session map to it.

```
Map<String, Object> rootMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
rootMap.put("session", sessionMap);
```

Then in template you can call it like that:

```
${session['A']}
```

Comment: No Aleksandra, its not working.Expression session is undefined on line 38  The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> ${session.getAttribute('A')} [on line 38, column 32 in

Answer (score 0):

There's no session object in freemarker, you should do something like

```
<#assign session = stack.findValue('#session')/>
```

The action code to execute would be

```
FreemarkerResult fr = new FreemarkerResult("SendEmail.ftl");
ActionContext.getContext().getContainer().inject(fr);
Writer out = new StringWriter();
fr.setWriter(out);
Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("A", A);
session.put("B", B);
fr.execute(ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation());
```

Comment: Let me check and come back

Comment: its not working, I know there is values in session, before I call freemarker template,I call jsp and output the session value and over there I can see values,${A};${B};<s:property value="#session['A']"/> and <s:property value="#session['B']"/>,but same<@s. does not work in freemarker.probably I need to enable deb ug on freemarker

Comment: How do you use a ftl, what result type did you return. Post `struts.xml`. You can try also `${stack.findValue('#session.A')}`.

Comment: My result type is not FTL,but jsp, I send out the email,and that email template is FTL.I store the session value in value stack and then want to access those values in FTL Template.I have action class which trigger the email class, and in that email class, I load FTL Template and do the required processing and once email is send.Everything works fine just that in FTL template I dont get the values.But values are there in jsp result type configured.

Comment: Post the code what are you doing, the code should be a self contained example. Can you access a value stack there?

Comment: added the relevant part of code Roman, Please see if you can think something,all I need is that from freemarker I need to access value stack data.

Comment: Do you think action chaining will help.Probably I can convert my sendEmail class to action and then I can chain the actions and see if it works.But I dont want to chain actions.

Comment: No, action chaining won't help. Create a freemarker result on the fly and execute it, set the writer to get output.